# Matplotlib tables layout issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to put a large table in an A4 report. pyplot.show() presents the layout such that the entire table is visible. However, pyplot.savefig() generates a pdf whereby the table is concealed by the graph. ([example of pdf concealing the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSdlo.png)) I would like to have the pdf show the entire table rather than concealing it. Please see below code for a summary of the issue.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox


def BadTable(savefile: str):
    fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(8.27, 11.69)) #A4 size                                                                                                                                      
    fig.suptitle('Title')

    gs = GridSpec(3, 1, figure=fig)
    ax_desc = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
    ax_table = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, :])
    ax_graph = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, :])

    #Description box                                                                                                                                                                                               
    TextBox(ax_desc, '', initial='Hello world')

    #Table                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    ax_table.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)

    nums = np.random.randint(0, 10, (30,10))
    ax_table.table(cellText=nums, colLabels=range(10), loc='center')
    ax_table.axis('off')
    ax_table.axis('tight')

    ax_graph.plot(range(20), range(20))

    if savefile is None:
        plt.show()
    elif type(savefile) is str:
        plt.savefig(savefile)
    else:
        raise Exception()

#Table fits                                                                                                                                                                                                        
BadTable(None)

#Table does not fit                                                                                                                                                                                                
BadTable('badpdf.pdf')
```

Answer (score 2):

First I'd like to mention that the behaviour which produces the best looking result is not necessarily "correct". Therefore I would generally advise to stick to a solution like the one in [@Patol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331948/4124317) which also theoretically gives the "correct" behaviour.

Concerning the issue, there is an intesting interplay between constrained_layout and the table cell height optimization.

To see that let's turn `constrained_layout` off. (Also make the plot half-tranparent to see that the table overlaps the plot and give it a background color to see its extent.)

Then compare to `constrained_layout=True` (on the right)

[image]
[image]

```css
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox


def BadTable(savefile: str):
    fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=False, figsize=(8.27, 11.69)) #A4 size                                                                                                                                      
    fig.suptitle('Title')

    gs = GridSpec(3, 1, figure=fig)
    ax_desc = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
    ax_table = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, :])
    ax_graph = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, :])

    #Description box                                                                                                                                                                                               
    TextBox(ax_desc, '', initial='Hello world')

    #Table                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    ax_table.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)

    nums = np.random.randint(0, 10, (30,10))
    ax_table.table(cellText=nums, colLabels=range(10), loc='center')
    ax_table.axis('off')
    ax_graph.patch.set_alpha(0.7)

    ax_graph.plot(range(20), range(20))

    if savefile is None:
        plt.show()
    elif type(savefile) is str:
        plt.savefig(savefile)
    else:
        raise Exception()

#Table does not fit                                                                                                                                                                                                
BadTable('badpdf.png')

plt.show()
```

Now constrained layout has, based on the original extend of the table, allocated space for the elements in the figure. The axes with the table in it has been given more space. 
However, the table, now having more space, will expand itself, because it thinks it can use that space. This leads to it overlapping again.

What you can do is reiterate this. Given the additional space, let constrained_layout optimize for space again, by drawing the figure yet another time,

```
fig.canvas.draw()
```

The amount of additional space will now be less than in the first step. Therefore the table will not grow any more, but rather redistribute the space given to it. (left)

Reiterating it yet another time, i.e. adding a second call to `fig.canvas.draw()` will finally let the race condition converge. (right)

[image]
[image]

Hence one possible solution is to call `draw()` at least twice before drawing again for the final saving

```
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.savefig(savefile)
```

Given the above, we can now answer the question: Why does `plt.show()` show the seemingly correct figure?
Because showing the figure, which is larger than the screen inside the GUI window will lead to the figure needing to resize. Each resize step will require the figure to be redrawn. So essentially you will get at least one additional draw step, and we've seen above that such additional draw step will have the effect of adjusting the table height such that no overlap occurs.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge, very interesting as always.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be looking for the `height_ratios` keyword for `GridSpec`?

`gs = GridSpec(3, 1, figure=fig, height_ratios=[1, 10, 4])` produces

[image]

[Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html) is a great guide as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my question actually pertains to why .show() does the layout correctly while .savefig() doesn't. I would much prefer a solution that can adapt to arbitrary table sizes (which .show() seems to do already)

Comment: `show` and `savefig` give the same behaviour on my machine. One thing though, if I expand the window produced by `show` and shrink it back to how it was, then I get the correct behaviour. To be faire, there is probably an answer by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest which explains this behaviour somewhere on StackOverflow. :)

Comment: I doubt there is an answer of mine explaining this. Also, first I'd like to mention that the behaviour which produces the best looking result is not necessarily the most "correct" one. I would be able to explain the behaviour, but I don't have much time right now. So I will give an answer in the evening or tomorrow, but in general, I would advise to use the solution presented in this answer here, effectively making the plot "correct" from the start.

Comment: Thanks. The table in question needs to be dynamic in length so the height ratio would have to be calculated (which is not really ideal imho). On the other hand, is there a mode whereby the fonts in the table would size such that the table would fit into the preassigned grid?